# postgresql trigger statement syntax (when data is in other table.)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to learn to create a trigger statement in PGSql, but I am having issues of passing my data column for this.

So, normally, I have something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsv_gin_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON MySuperTable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE  PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger(content_tsv_gin,'public.wtf',content)
```

Here, `content` and `content_tsv_gin` are simply columns on `MySuperTable` - and this works great.

However, what I'd like to have is the `content` comming from another table andnot `MySuperTable`. So, I have tried something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsv_gin_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON MySuperTable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger(content_tsv_gin,'public.wtf',nt.content) FROM NewTable nt;
```

.. This does not work and throws me an error... So, I'd like to know how I can pass a data column from another table into the TRIGGER statement - if this is possible at all...

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but can't you pass the column / table name as text and get the data from within the trigger function?

Comment: @mlinth: Do you know of an example for this?

Comment: Well, the function called by the trigger can contain any SQL statements, so you can just build a regular select query. You're going to have to roll your own function anyway...